# opening a self-opening, password protected archive with .zip.exe extension on a Mac

Tags: zip, 7-zip

I am trying to open a password protected file:

`unzip -v -P password123 filename.zip.exe`

The output I get is:
 `Archive:  filename.zip.exe End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive. unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of filename.zip.exe or filename.zip.exe.zip, and cannot find filename.zip.exe.ZIP, period.`

1. Ideas how can I debug this?
2. Is there a way to check if the file is corrupted? (It has been moved multiple times)
3. Where could I download an example .exe.zip file to test if I can generally open those from my laptop?

Comment: Try to rename `filename.zip.exe` to `filename.zip`.

Comment: …or try a 'smart' unzipper like [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) (freeware). The built-in zip archiver is not very clever with Windows-specific tweaks to common formats.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Changing the file name did not help and Keka is giving me an error

Comment: You indicate your file is *.zip.exe. This is not a normal file structure in Windows and looks like a file structure a virus would use. With the caution, try using 7z to open the archive. If 7z cannot open it, it isn't an archive.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the file?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is sensitive data :/

Comment: I'd get the sender to re-up in a better format. Just a password-protected zip, without the extra windows-only baggage. Otherwise you're going to need access to a Win machine.

Answer (score 1):

The self-extracting zip files that I know of all work by simply appending a zip file to the end of an executable (that handles the unzipping). The `unzip` program knows all about that and should be able to unzip it.

Given that you have tried `unzip` and it hasn't found the zip payload suggests something else is going on.

Can you try running `7z l  filename.zip.exe` to see if it can find the zip data.

Next see what the `file` command thinks your `filename.zip.exe` file actually is.

```
file filename.zip.exe
```

That should report it as some form of executable. I ran the command against a windows self-extracting zip file and got this

```
$ file test.exe
test.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

If that shows that you do have an executable, the next thing is to see if there is any zip file data embedded in it. To do that, download [zipdetails](https://github.com/pmqs/zipdetails/blob/main/bin/zipdetails) and run

```
perl zipdetails -v --scan filename.zip.exe
```

If it finds zip data it will output a lot of text about the zip file. If it outputs a message saying that it is not a zip file, you either don't have a self-extracting zip file or it uses another technique to embed a zip file in an executable.

Answer (score 0):

In the above error message in the original question I was using a MacBook to open the file. I borrowed a Windows laptop and tried opening it from there. On Windows, everything was easy and straightforward. Thank you for all suggestions!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).